# Single actor executing on scheduled interval, how to shut down inbetween execution?

Tags: akka, actor

I have a single actor spawned by a call scheduler.schedule like so:

```
val yelpActor = actorSystem.actorOf(YelpActor.props, "yelpActor")
actorSystem.scheduler.schedule(0.seconds, 3.hour, yelpActor, Start(browser, mailActor, mailer, reviewsTable))
```

I want it to execute its code and shutdown after it runs, then startup again when 3 hour mark occurs (then shut down again etc).

Actor is defined like this:

```
class YelpActor extends Actor {
  import YelpActor._

def receive = {
case Start(browser, mailActor, mailer, reviewsTable) =>
 .....

  }
}
```

What do I call within the Actor to make sure this happens correctly?

EDIT:

The reason I'm asking this questions is because the memory in my JVM is slowly filling up and causing OOM's. From metrics, it appears to be making a step in memory consumption everytime this scheduler runs (every 3 hours) See below, the red circles are when I re-deployed.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by shut down? Can you add the code where you create your actor and also the full scheduler invocation?

Comment: Every time the scheduler runs does it just send a message to a singleton YelpActor or create a new one? If the latter, the old one needs to be killed